# Can an iOS app monitor the disable timer or be notified when the system dims the screen before timing out and backgrounding the app?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

Updated question so comments from 8/31 don't really apply to this version.

Can I be made aware of when the system automatically dims the screen before timing out and moving the app to the background?

I would then like to play a sound to get the users attention so they can interact with the app to prevent it from being backgrounded.

In the event the user does not disable the idle timer, I want to give them the opportunity to interact with the app to keep it active and in the foreground.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO/YES];
```

**I set up a notification to inform me when the screen dims:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method:) name:UIScreenBrightnessDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

**but that does not seem to detect when the system dims the screen.**

It does detect when I programmatically change the brightness, but that does me no good as far as addressing the automatic dimming performed by the system.

If I can't detect the dimming, can I monitor the timer and somehow determine the timing of when the screen gets dimmed?

Comment: This can't be done. You can get notified that the app is entering the background but you can't stop it. There is no way to confirm with the user that the app should go into the background or stay in the foreground.

Comment: The home button click handler is a CGS function that you have neither access too, nor clearance to call.

Comment: Yeah, only after extensive research and question composition did I come across information saying you can not override the home key press. However, since that is a user action I am not concerned so much. I would still like to somehow catch the case where the app times out. I had hoped to be notified of the screen dimming to play an alert sound so the user can take action before the backgrounding.